# jQuery UI datepicker css

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I need to apply custom style to datepicker. I found http://www.themeroller.com/ but the output css seems too heavy to me.

Can I use datepicker without linking to native styles (ui.datepicker.css or jquery-ui.css) and create css for elements I need to customize only?
Or may be I have to make custom css with http://www.themeroller.com/ and than edit it. Which way?

Comment: use ThemeRoller... it would be very difficult to roll your own manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#theming for documentation on how to theme the datepicker.